# Iphone/Ipad Google Maps Iframe Embed

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, iframe

I have a google map embedded in an Iframe. Just something like:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.de/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=51.151786,10.415039&
amp;spn=23.5119,51.723633&amp;t=h&amp;z=5&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

In Browsers this is just fine but the Iphone/Ipad tries to load an App. Which seems just to work fine (dont have one myself), but the page loads and the user gets a popup message asking if he wants to run the app. Is there a way to just display the map in the Iframe?

Comment: Interesting question. Can't say I've ever seen a website that did this. It always seems to load an app. Granted I don't use the web browser in my iPhone much....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to load the Google Maps using the Google Maps API directly.

I faced the problem recently and I found the code in [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) very complete and useful.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I have a Google map on my website's contact us page, embedded according to the code Google Maps gave me. It does not work in an iPhone. Clicking "view larger map" or something similar takes me to the Google Maps app, which works, but the map on the website shows blank, with the following text: `Sign in, View in Mobile | Classic, (c) 2012 - Privacy, Loading...` with `Mobile` selected and `Loading...` has an icon that spins forever.

Comment: Unfortunately I think people will be using the embed method in the first place because it's far easier than using the API.

Answer (score -1):

i guess it's not the right way to load a googleMap in html/iFrame...

i was interested too, that's how i managed (and it works fine in a iFrame): using "apple iWeb" widget google map... it's a low cost software...

it's my html code in "myGoogleMap.html" (after i trashed all unused html):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it" lang="it">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <meta name="iWeb-Build" content="local-build-20110308" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=700" />
    <title>Testo
</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="Vuoto_files/Vuoto.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen,print' href='Vuoto_files/VuotoIE.css'/><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 8]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen,print' href='Media/IE8.css'/><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/iWebSite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Widgets/SharedResources/WidgetCommon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Widgets/GoogleMap/GoogleMap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Vuoto_files/Vuoto.js"></script>
  </head>
<body style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0) margin: 0pt; " onload="onPageLoad();" onunload="onPageUnload();">

    <div class="com-apple-iweb-widget-GoogleMap aboveStrokesAndFrames" id="widget1"
   style="height: 400px; left: 0px; opacity: 1.00; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 320px; z-index: 1; ">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
new GoogleMap('widget1', 'Scripts/Widgets/GoogleMap', 'Scripts/Widgets/SharedResources', '.', {"language": "it", "showInfo": "0", "locatedAddressIsFromGeocoder": "1", "unlocatedAddress": "", "zoomLevel": "6", "center": "51.261915,10.151367", "locatedAddressPoint": "19.56661,-99.134932", "locatedAddress": "my address in Mexico, Pico de Orizaba 3A, Lomas de Cuautepec, Delegazione Gustavo A. Madero, Cittá del Messico, Distrito Federal, Messico", "showGoogleBar": "1", "showMarker": "1", "showZoom": "1"});
//--><!]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and i load it in one other html with this:

```
<iframe width="320" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" src="Sito-test/myGoogleMap.html">
</iframe>
```

of course you need the javaScript made by iWeb too, but i'm not sure i can legally show them...

anyway, the point is that now you know that it's possible to load it in a iFrame without the "installing app question"...